# I am getting a error trying to UPDATE a column value mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database

So here is the table

[image]

I am trying to update the status of all `city`'s(VARCHAR) with the name `London` with the value (TINYINT) 45.

This is my query

```
UPDATE supplier
SET status = 45
WHERE city = ‘ London‘;
```

This is the error message I get but I can not see the syntax error

[image]

The result should be that all city names London will have the status 45

Comment: I am not sure but I think London should be wrapped by single `' '`or double quotes`" "`.     
  `UPDATE supplier SET status = 45 WHERE city = "London";`

Comment: Use `'` to enclose strings. You're writing a query, not an essay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of quotes. `‘` is not the same thing as `'`. Ensure you're using proper single quotes (And not fancy unicode ones):

```
UPDATE supplier
SET status = 45
WHERE city = 'London';
```

See the differences in quotes [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL and probably many other RDMS, backticks are used for table and column identifiers,  although not mandatory at all... except if your identifier is a reserved keyword or contains whitespace(s) or other specific charatacters ([see mysql doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)).

On the other hand, single quotes are used for string values everywhere, in insert statement, update statement, where clause, ... . There are also often used for dates.

That's why, as it has been suggested, you should write :

```
UPDATE supplier
SET status = 45
WHERE city = 'London';
```